# What are the best practices for consuming ASP.NET Web Api with oAuth in Ionic Framework?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, asp.net-web-api2

#### Summary:

Suppose I have a ASP.NET WebAPI2 Application as my back-end and for security it uses oAuth (bearer access tokens). Now i want to consume this Web API in my Ionic Application ( which uses AngularJS). What are the best practices to deal with the authorization and retrieval and refreshing access tokens in Ionic Framework?

#### More info:

Let's suppose i have +100 different AJAX calls to my web api. I want the functionality that if the server challenged an authentication (i.e no access token or it is expired), then i show the login form and eventually get the access token and save it for subsequent calls. And also somehow i should send the access token along with every other request. Obviously i can't write some code and duplicate it for each and every request that need authorization. So i'm looking for the best practices/implementations to handle authentication situations like this in Ionic Framework (AngularJS). Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use AngularJS interceptor for this task, it will be vary similar to the code below:

```
app.factory('authInterceptorService', ['$q', '$location', 'localStorageService', function ($q, $location, localStorageService) {

var authInterceptorServiceFactory = {};

var _request = function (config) {

    config.headers = config.headers || {};

    var authData = localStorageService.get('authorizationData');
    if (authData) {
        config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + authData.token;
    }

    return config;
}

var _responseError = function (rejection) {
    if (rejection.status === 401) {
        $location.path('/login');
    }
    return $q.reject(rejection);
}

authInterceptorServiceFactory.request = _request;
authInterceptorServiceFactory.responseError = _responseError;

return authInterceptorServiceFactory;
```

}]);

I have written detailed blog post on how to send access token from AngularJS app to Web Api back-end in a centralized place that you do not need to duplicate any code. You can check the post title "[AngularJS Token Authentication using ASP.NET Web API 2, Owin, and Identity](http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/09/angularjs-token-authentication-using-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/)"